# Format DataFrame to Achieve Equal Number of Digits in Each Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, trailing

I would like to format the DataFrame

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.012 | 3.2 | nan |
| 0 | -1 | 15.2 |
| 0.5 | 7.53 | 76.88 |

using trailing zeros, such that all values in each column have the same number of digits.
The result should look like this:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.012 | 3.20 | nan |
| 0.000 | -1.00 | 15.20 |
| 0.500 | 7.53 | 76.88 |

In the initial DataFrame, all values are `strings`

Comment: Have you tried formatting the columns? `df['col1'] = df['col1'].map('${:,.3f}'.format)`

Comment: @Michael, did the solution for worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.applymap(float)
```

```
      Col1   Col2    Col3
1   -0.012   3.20     NaN
2    0.000  -1.00   15.20
3    0.500   7.53   76.88
```

data use

```
data={'Col1': {1: '-0.012 ', 2: '0', 3: '0.5'},
 'Col2': {1: '3.2', 2: '-1', 3: '7.53'},
 'Col3': {1: np.nan, 2: '15.2', 3: '76.88'}}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    Col1    Col2    Col3
1   -0.012    3.2    NaN
2    0       -1     15.2
3    0.5     7.53   76.88
```